# Removing spell check error for filename in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

This has been annoying me for way too long. How do I remove the red underline under filename? I've gone through inspections and disabled spell check from there. I've disabled PEP8.

How do I remove that line? Any help would be much appreciated!

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0icb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file is highlighted in the editor tab and the project view only if it contains errors; typos are not considered errors. There must have been a different error within the file (you can find it by looking at red lines in the right margin of the editor).

I think you ment to write `print("Hi")` and not `print "Hi"`